# how to calculate the cross product of two multidimensional matrices

Tags: matrices, cross-product

Is the cross product of two 3x3 matrices even defined? Certainly for the dot product we say that the dot product of two 3x1 vectors is a scalar but the dot product of two 3x3 matrices is a 3x3 matrix. Since the cross product of two 3x1 vectors is a 3x1 vector, would we by analogy say that the cross product of two 3x3 matrices would be a 3x3x3 matrix? And would we calculate the third dimension as the vector product of the two 3x1 vectors where they intersect?

Comment: The short answer is no, the cross product only refers to vectors in R3. The long answer is that there is something like a cross product in higher dimensions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator

Comment: WOW! What a pandora's box. Their statement 'a Hodge star is a one-to-one mapping of k-vectors to (n – k)-vectors' is confusing. But I get their analogy to the familiar geometric definition of the cross product as the vector perpendicular to the plane defined by the two 3x1 vectors. So if I had a volume defined by three vectors, a cross product of these three vectors would give a fourth vector perpendicular to this object?

Comment: yes that is correct- but the hodge star is more general. You can think of the Hodge star of the subspace defined by k unit length orthogonal basis vectors as being the surface defined of the "rest" of the n-k basis vectors. For example in four dimensions the hodge star of a plane is also a plane.

Comment: The dot product of 2 matrices =sum of products of corresponding elements is a scalar. The outer product of 2 matrices, also called the Kronecker product, is useful too. Cross-product is defined only for vectors of 3 components but the entries can come from any field, not necessarily the real numbers. I can think of at least 3 different products of vectors with 4 components (i) quaternions (ii) put them as rows in a 4x4 matrix with the standard vectors along the top and take  the formal determinant (iii) 2 points in projective 3-space -take the line coordinates of the line joining the points.

Comment: I wish there was a youtube video on this. I know it's complicated but all the big words throw me off. Sorry if I sound like a moron but reading the wiki pages is like a foreign language and there's no dictionary or thesaurus. Maybe I've become spoiled by people like 3B1B,Veritasium, and Physics Explained. Khan Academy just goes over the basic cross product and dot product.

Comment: @Bernard I get this ' in four dimensions the hodge star of a plane is also a plane. ' since n-k in this case = 2. But I wish Sal Khan would show me how to calculate it.

Comment: @P.Lawrence  from this 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product' I get that Kronecker product is like taking each element of one matrix(a,b) and treating it like scalar multiplication on the entire second matrix(p,q) to get a matrix which has a x b x p x q entries and shape (b x p, a x q)   ( by 'x' I just mean simple multiplication)

Comment: @P.Lawrence a quaternion has 4 components. So to get the cross product you would need 4 of them? Or would you need to define a new direction , r, so that the first row would be 'i,j,k,r' and then line up 3 quaternions underneath it as rows to get a 4 x 4 matrix .This would be more analogous to how we calculate the cross product of two 3,1 vectors in 3d space where the first row is 'i,j,k'

Comment: I am also awed by the ability to get the projection of one vector onto another by taking the dot product. If I defined an object as a 3 x 3 x 3 matrix where each entry is a coordinate in 3d space(a 3x1 vector) . Each vector basically points to a'particle' of the object. I  have a 4d object with 3 x 3 x3 x3 entries. How could I figure out the 2d shadow of this object (onto the x,y plane for example) ? Is there a dot product that will do it?

Comment: There are many interesting products of 4-element vectors but I wouldn't call any of those products a "cross-product." I reserve the term "cross-product" for the standard cross-product of two 3-element vectors.